# How to reset a global variable and pass it to Decorator

Tags: python, function, decorator, python-3.8

How can I pass the latest value of A and B to Decorator ?

I have to following code,

```
A = "orginary"
B = "guy"

def caller_func(**kwargs):
 # few lines of logic here 
 global A , B
 A = "Super"
 B = "Mario"
 decorated_fn_1(**kwargs)

@some_decorator(
new_a = A
new_B = B)
def decorated_fn_1(**kwargs):
 # few lines of logic here 
 # decorator functionality called 


"""
Note: Assume some_decorator does something with A and B

"""
```

Objective is to make the latest variable value for A and B to the decorator.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using globals, I would make the decorator accept additional arguments on behalf of the function. The wrapper can provide some defaults, and they can be optionally overriden if required:

```
def some_decorator(a, b):
    def inner(func):
        def wrapper(*args, a=a, b=b, **kwargs):
            print(f"{a=}, {b=}")
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return inner


@some_decorator(1, 2)
def foo(var):
    print(var)


foo("test1")
foo("test2", a=3, b=4)
```

Outputs:

```
a=1, b=2
test1
a=3, b=4
test2
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I like the Idea, but my need is to make the inner function variables available to the Decorator. I m restricted on the above code signature in my question. I can remove the Globals though.